# redirect from method with http DELETE type to method with GET type

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I send my request using jquery ajax with type "DELETE". At server side I have approprite handle method that looks like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String delete(@RequestParam("hotel") String hotelCode, @PathVariable Long id, Model model){
        //delete operation
        return "redirect:/HotelTaxesAndCharges?hotel="+hotelCode;
    }
```

and method to which I want to redirect my call after delete looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(@RequestParam("hotel") String hotelCode, Model model){
    //logic
    return 'getAll';
}
```

so when i call delete method during execution I'm getting error "you can redirect to JSP using only GET PUT or HEAD methods". I found solution using HiddenHttpMethodFilter, but result code looks little messy and I need to send request using POST and adding additional parameter (_method) to requst with custom request type.

So my question is there any other solution for DELETE/REDIRECT/GET transformation.

SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH

**UPDATE**
[image]

so you can that it redirects using delete too. And if I change everything from delete to post I get this:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the error? How exactly does the error message look?

Comment: @axtavt, I get error during redirect and error message now looks like this "Request method 'DELETE' not supported". And I don't know how convert request type from delete to redirect.

Comment: If I you POST type instead of DELETE everything works fine

Comment: Could you spy the dialog between your browser and you server (wireshark is good at that) ? I tried a redirect in following method of a stripped down controller `@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.DELETE) public String delete(HttpServletRequest req) { return "redirect:/welcome"; }`, called it with a `DELETE` method and ... got a correct redirect response. I think the problem is not in spring-mvc (using spring 3.2.4 and tomcat 7)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I add two screenshots. During first you can see error during redirect process because result method request type = GET. At  the second screenshot you can see that if I change delete to Post everything goes well and result method is GET

Comment: If you are using a DELETE request redirecting doesn't make any sense. Read my answer here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996779/cannot-handle-302-redirect-in-ajax-and-why/15996968#15996968. It's not entirely the same but the same principle applies.

Answer (score 8):

What happens is normal even if it is not what you need :

- you submit a DELETE request from ajax
- Spring controller receives it and answers a "redirect:/.../Hotel..."
- Spring ViewResolver sends a redirect response with code 302 and correct Location header
- **browser uses precedent method and new location** (normal for 302) issuing a DELETE (when you expected a get)
- Spring DispatcherServlet receives a `DELETE /.../Hotel...` when `@RequestMapping` is for method=GET
- Spring DispatcherServlet correctly states that no controller is defined and issues an error

All that is confirmed by your wireshark traces

It works when you send a POST request, because for compatibility with HTTP 1.0, all major browsers use a GET for a redirection following a POST like if status was 303

There is an immediate workaround : allow your method for the redirected URL to accept DELETE in addition to GET. Not very expensive, but not very nice.

You could also manage the redirection on client side : simply send a 200 code that will received by ajax, and let ajax do the redirection

The last solution consist in using a 303 code that explicitely ask browser to issue a GET independently of what was previous method. You can hardcode it by having your controller request take the HttpServletResponse as paremeter and return a null. You then manually add `Location` header and 303 status code.

But you can also configure the `InternalResourceViewResolver` to return 303 codes instead of 302 by setting its redirectHttp10Compatible attribute to false. You simple declare a bean in your servlet application context and Spring will use it. But you loose compatibility with older browsers that would not support HTTP 1.1 and 303 status code.

Comment: I understand better why you got +100k reputations. Thanks.