# Handle 302-redirect in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have backbone application in which I need to take care if the user lost a session. When the session is lost, server sends 302 (redirect to login page). That works in some cases, and in other it does not.

I have made a ajax request that ping the server in intervals confirming the session. I have read the many topics on SO, such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996779/cannot-handle-302-redirect-in-ajax-and-why)

And there it says, that browser handles 302's.

I am confused here.
This is the simple Ajax request that I use to ping the server:

```
setInterval(function () {
        if(baseHref){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: baseHref + "api/ping",
                success: function (data) {                        
                    if(data !== true){

                        window.location.href = baseHref + "login";
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
    },5000);
```

In local environment, when the session is lost, server sends 302 and I end up in success every time and I can make decision based on it.
On the development environment (https://xxxxxx.com) I never end up in any of the promises, Browser overrides them.

One solution is to talk to server people and have them send me object, and not 302. But before I make my demand I would like to know:

Why does it work in localhost? By all means it should not.

Comment: what response do you see in network tab of developer tool ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: When the session is lost (localhost), I get 302 and the Ajax success data contains the form in html, along with some Javascript to handle the form

Comment: @ivarni I don't think this is duplicate, as I have stated another question on SO. My question is why it does work on localhost :)

Comment: How are you running the app locally? The server is returning an error, but i'm assuming you're not running a 'server' to host the files locally.

Comment: Server is TomCat and it delivers the files.

Comment: There are a slew of reasons why status 302 would not work as intended, but could this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5044931/1670474 be the issue?

Comment: You should look into the server sending a 401 (not authorized) and then redirect back to the login page. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses