# zk-grails and spring security integration

Tags: spring, grails, zk

I have an application in grails 2.3.11 with zk-grails plugin. when I perform spring security core integration for authentication, the zul pages stop responding, giving the following error: "The server is temporarity out of service
Woud you like try again?
(Unxpected token <(SyntaxError)) "

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your security configuration intercepts the Ajax servlet mapped to /zkau (independent of grails).

ZK's client engine expects ajax requests to respond with a JSON like format, and not a redirection to a login page (which is usually html). Hence the unexpected token '<' - html pages usually start with a '<', the response parsing simply fails due to a wrong format.

Your next question might be ... why doesn't ZK's client engine detect redirects on ajax responses? 
-> Simply because it can't. Already discussed multiple times (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996779/cannot-handle-302-redirect-in-ajax-and-why) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589))

A Feature request to support modern browser's API's is already posted for a future version -> [ZK-4175](https://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-4175?jql=project%20in%20(ZKCHARTS%2C%20ZK)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22fetch%20api%22%20ORDER%20BY%20fixVersion%20ASC) and to improve the error messages [ZK-4199](https://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-4199).

So as of now you have multiple choices:

1. for unauthorized AJAX requests to /zkau respond with a 401 (unauthorized) instead
   of a 302 redirect and configure a client side [error-code +
   reload-uri](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Configuration_Reference/zk.xml/The_client-config_Element/The_error-reload_Element)
2. instead of a 401 you can return a JSON response that ZK's client engine understands
   e.g.:
   {"rs":[["redirect",["https://yourssoserver.com/login.jsp",""]]],"rid":1}
3. as a last resort customize ZK's client side parser error handling as discussed in the [zk forums](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/101228/better-error-message-when-zkau-response-isnt-json/). and implement your own logic to handle certain non JSON responses.

**UPDATE:** [ZK-4199](https://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-4199) has been implemented and will be included in ZK version 8.6.2 (displaying a more meaningful error message)